# In Standard Model, are both the Higgs doublet and its complex conjugate present in the universe, or not the complex conjugate one?

Tags: higgs

In Standard Model, the Higgs doublet is \begin{equation}
\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{c}\phi^+\\ \phi^0\end{array}\right)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi_1+i\phi_2\\
\phi_3+i\phi_4
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

The complex conjugate of Higgs double is

\begin{equation}
\Phi^*=\left(\begin{array}{c}\phi^-\\ \phi^{0*}\end{array}\right)
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi_1-i\phi_2\\
\phi_3-i\phi_4
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation}

Question : restricting to the topic of Higgs physics, what is present in the universe :

1. The Higgs doublet only ?
2. The complex conjugate of the Higgs doublet ?
3. Both the Higgs doublet and its complex conjugate ?

The picture in wikipedia there :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_formulation_of_the_Standard_Model#/media/File:Standard_Model_Of_Particle_Physics--Most_Complete_Diagram.png

would make believe that only the Higgs doublet is present in the universe. But is it true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two field doublets you are writing down involve the same four $\phi_i$s, and they constitute different arrangements of them, so they make no difference in the amplitudes involved and their physics implications. (The physical Higgs particle is linked to $\phi_3-v$.)

They are all "present" in our universe, as would any other rewriting of them, such as $\tilde \Phi$, etc...  As long as the interactions and couplings of each are specified clearly, and each is fit into the SM we know, there should be no issue. Recall both $\Phi$ and $\Phi^*$ are present in the real covariant kinetic term in the SM Lagrangian written in the practical notation.

Comment: $W^+$ "eats" $\phi^+$. $W^-$ "eats" $\phi^-$. $Z$ "eats" $i\phi_4$. So "who" eats $-i\phi_4$ ?

Comment: If you look at the relevant "eating term" resulting from the Higgs covariant derivative squared, *that* involves both a $\Phi$ and a $\Phi^*$, and amounts to $g^2v^2 (Z^\mu/sin \theta_w -\partial^\mu \phi_4/gv )^2/2$,  so the *Z* ate $\sin\theta_w~ \phi_4/gv$ gauged into it. Both the i and the -i play a role, and neither features in the gauge absorption by the Z.

Comment: And, of course, nobody eats $\phi_3 -v$, which is why the Higgs particle is around...